# Ruby on Rails sub domain hosting for some controller only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns

I developed a ruby on rails project which is hosted on http://example.com. Now i want to start a new sub domain something like http://api.example.com

My problem is i developed main domain files and sub-domain file in single project. Now i want to match only some of the controllers to sub-domain (api related controllers) and remaining controllers to main-domain.

How can achieve this?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Rails 2: http://railscasts.com/episodes/123-subdomains
Rails 3: http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

Rails 3 approach: You basically just add the desired controller to your constraint. If you want to keep your subdomains static etc, you need to modify the code from that screencast. Untested example:

```
class ApiSubdomain
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain == 'api'
  end
end

constraints(ApiSubdomain) do
  # your api routes here
end
```

Comment: However, if you want to create an API, you may want to have a look at grape. https://github.com/intridea/grape